# Is Integrate antidifferentiate?

Tags: integration, functions, derivatives

I'm still introducing myself in derivation, antiderivation and integrals, because I haven't studied it in class yet (I will study it next year and derivation in some months), but well, about my question I have seen that integrals and antiderivatives, at least, looks like the same, so, is that true? and also I didn't understand at all why the integration gives you the area, I mean, realize that derivation gives you the value of the slope is easy, but why the antiderivation gives you the area is a bit harder for me to understand, thanks!

Comment: What is the rate of change of the area of a function? The height of the function i.e. the function itself (a taller function accumulates area faster than a shorter function, and a negative height decreases area).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. Cf. [the fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus)

Comment: Regarding antiderivates as "area", look at [What's an intuitive explanation for integration?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/916569/139123) I think [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4187878/139123) gives a good explanation of how you could get "area under the curve" from an integral. BTW I honestly don't know why that's not the top-voted answer; [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/916650/139123) was only meant to supplement it.

Comment: Perhaps helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1991575/why-cant-the-second-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus-be-proved-in-just-two-lines/1991585#1991585

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two types of integrals:

- Definite integrals, which are more-or-less just straight-out defined to be the area under a curve,

and

- Indefinite integrals, which are exactly the same thing as anti-derivatives, but we gave them a second name.

So, why are there two different things with remarkably similar names? Because there's this amazing discovery, called The Fundamental Theorem Of Calculus, that shows that they are damn near the same thing. So what you'll want to do is understand why the FTC is true. But it's brilliant and not at all obvious, so give yourself some time to reach a full understanding of it.

(It's worth noting that all mathematicians have fully absorbed the FTC, and so they often aren't very clear about which type of integral they are taking about at any particular moment, as the FTC lets them switch back and forth. It makes things easier for them, but can make things harder for students who are just learning calc. I apologize in advance for any confusion you personally may experience because of this.)

Comment: +1 Lovely answer, informal but correct and entirely appropriate for the level of the question.

Comment: Thank you, @EthanBolker. I did skip any details (maybe that's why the down votes?), but the question shows that the OP is thinking about what's actually going on, and the distinction between definite and indefinite integrals so often gets glossed over, it felt worth addressing.

Comment: To the OP: I'll drop a [link to another answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4595908/understanding-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus-part-2/4596160#4596160) that's kind of similar, but addresses a question that's about some details of the proof of the FTC. It might be useful to you once you start getting into the details yourself

Answer (score 2):

**The following is a rough illustration to demonstrate why the antiderivative of a function gives the area.**

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $F: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be positive, differentiable functions such that $F(x)$ is the area between the graph of $f$ and the $x$-axis in the interval $(0,x)$.

Consider that $F(x + \Delta) - F(x)$ is the area between the graph of $f$ and the $x$-axis in the interval $(x,x+\Delta)$. Now, for small $\Delta$ we have $F(x + \Delta) - F(x) \approx \Delta f(x)$. Thus,

$$ \frac{1}{\Delta} \cdot \Big[ F(x + \Delta) - F(x) \Big] \approx \Delta f(x) \cdot \frac{1}{\Delta} $$

$$ \frac{F(x + \Delta) - F(x)}{\Delta} \approx f(x) $$

and as $\Delta \to 0$ we have $\frac{F(x + \Delta) - F(x)}{\Delta} \to f(x)$. This latter point is more obvious when you consider $F(x + \Delta) - F(x) \to \Delta f(x)$ as $\Delta \to 0$. So, in the limit we have

$$ \lim_{\Delta \to 0} \frac{F(x + \Delta) - F(x)}{\Delta} = \lim_{\Delta \to 0} f(x) = f(x) $$

Notice the far left hand side of the equation satisfies the definition of a derivative. Thus,

$$ \frac{d}{dx} F(x) = f(x) $$

Hence, by definition of derivative, $f$ is the derivative of the function $F$ that conveys the area between $f$ and the $x$-axis. Or in other words, the antiderivative of $f$ is a function $F$ that conveys the area between $f$ and the $x$-axis.