# Why add the integration constant if we are not trying to find the anti-derivative?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I completely understand why we add **C** when we want an anti-derivative, but finding anti-derivatives is not integration, integration is meant to caculate the accumulations of values or the area under the curve, so do we have to add **C** when **Integrating**? (not anti-differentiating)

Does the integration constant come up when integrating from first principles? If not, why are definite integration defined using anti-derivatives instead of being defined from the "first principles of integration"?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. Although any area is expressible as a definite integral, that's not actually the _point_ of definite integrals, let alone indefinite ones. With which definitions of each type of integral are you familiar? Because if you asked me for a first-principles definition of a definite integral, mine would be in terms of limits of families of sums, and then one would prove how this is connected to antiderivatives, areas and so on.

Comment: Nobody "adds C". It is a notation and as such a convention. It is meant to express that the equation $y'(x)=f(x)$ has only unique solutions up to a constant summand. However, notations also depend on context. You won't find $\ldots + C$ in a scientific publication. Your question has no meaningful answer as long as its context isn't specified. Considering an integral as a volume element is a rather narrow perspective.

Comment: @J.G. Well, yes the area is not the definite integral, but the accumulations IS, the definition that i know (taking into account that i don't know much) is basically a limit to an infinite sum, so i think it's the same thing you're describing

Answer (score 3):

I'll try to answer some of your questions, albeit out of order.

(1) *"Why are definite integration defined using anti-derivatives?"* This is because we have the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. It is usually broken up into two parts for which in this context we would apply part II: (we have some conditions) and the definite integral can be evaluated as the difference of the antiderivative $F(x)$ at the endpoints. $$\int_a^b f(x)dx = F(b)-F(a).$$

This $F(x)$ may or may not be an elementary function. If you put $+C$ they will simply get cancelled out by the subtraction.

Definite integration is an analytic and geometric problem, whereas indefinite integration is an algebraic problem. The use of the $+C$ in $$\int2xdx = x^2 +C$$ communicates that we have a family of functions which could be the antiderivative---it is *indefinite*. Because when we differentiate the RHS, we get $2x$. Honestly, the $+C$ is overrated and often made fun of. Some teachers will even mark you wrong if you forget the $+C$ in the previous example, but this nonsense. In Integral Bees, such as the infamous MIT Integration Bee, they don't care about the $+C$ because *any* antiderivative will do to solve the integral (expressed as an elementary function).

The use of infinite sums to compute areas came before the FTC, and probably before the problem of indefinite integration, so there was no $+C$ around.

Finally, where is the $+C$ important? It is important when we have some type of initial conditions like in differential equations or integral equations.

Comment: Good observation about needing the $+C$ when satisfying initial (and boundary) conditions when solving differential equations. +1.

Comment: I would say (somewhat equivalently) that the $+C$ is important when you're going to do something else with the integral besides calculate a definite integral. Such as when you solve a DE like $y' = y$ and you go from $\ln y = x + C$ to $y = A e^x$.

Comment: actually that's why i asked the last question, since **C** is going to cancel out, why do we add it when integrating.(again, **integrating** not antidifferentiating )

Comment: When you do definite integration, you don't put the $+C$. Otherwise, show us an example that does.

Comment: I disagree that it is nonsense that a missing "+C" is marked as an error. This "+C" is important because the antiderivate is not unique. For definite integrals , this is of course irrelevant since the constant cancels out anyway.

Answer (score 2):

"... why are definite integration defined using anti-derivatives instead of being defined from the "first principles of integration"?

They aren't defined that way, they are computed that way. And they're computed that way because it's so much easier to do it that way.

Here's a brief discussion: [Is Integrate antidifferentiate?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4803320/is-integrate-antidifferentiate/4803338#4803338)

And here's a more detailed discussion: [Understanding The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, Part 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4595908/understanding-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus-part-2/4596160#4596160)

Comment: Since when are definite integration **defined** using anti-derivatives? I know that was what the OP said, but you didn't correct them either and went with it.

Comment: @Divide1918 - Ooh, good catch, thanks. I'll confess that because the two linked answers are all about the distinction, I quickly grabbed a quote from the question without fully parsing it. I've updated my answer to include your observation. Thx again.

Answer (score 1):

The indefinite integral is the anti derivative.

The definition that you hav in mind is the definition of the [(Riemann) integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral). If you look in the link such integral is defined over an interval.

the definition of the **indefinite** integral of a continuos function $f(t)$ is the function $y(x)$ such that
$$
y'(x)= f(x)
$$
see e.g. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative)

Such definition happen to coincide with the Riemann integral (at least in the case $f$ is continuos)

Answer (score 1):

I want to add a perspective that does not use volumes to consider integrals.

An integral is a solution to a differential equation. Differential equations can be visualized by their corresponding vector field and the integral can be considered as a flow through this vector field. There are many possible flows through a vector field, all depending on where we start. The constant $C$ can be regarded as the parameter that determines the starting point.
[image: predator-prey system]